# Finding an approximation for 'e' using the first n + 1 terms of continued fraction in python

Tags: python

I have tried to follow the continued fraction example of `[a1, a2, a3...]` in wiki. When I run the program I am able to obtain result for `n = 2` as `2.727272...75`
but when I try `n = 3` there are two outputs and they are lower (getting `2.394` and second line `2.3333`...)
I am not sure whether I need to add another set to the `y =...` line. If so do I have to add another set of `i -1+` so on to `y` each time I change `n`?
And why am I getting two lines of answer? Is it problem with how I have done the loop?

Here's my code:

```
n = abs(int(input("Enter number: ")))
y = 0
d = 0

for i in range(n, 1, -1):
    if i == n:
        y = (i - 1) + ((i - 1)/((i-1)/(i + (i/(i + 1))))
        d = d + y
    else:
        d = i + 1

    e = 2 + (1/d)

    print (e)
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question as text (not as an image, or as a link). You can get code formatting by highlighting it and clicking the `{}` button in the editor (or you can indent everything by an extra four spaces yourself).

Comment: For any `i` after the first one, you never use `y` at all. All you do is compute `d` directly from `i` (ignoring its previous value) and then compute `e` from `d`. I'm not sure I understand which continued fraction you're trying to implement, so I can't really suggest a fix.

Comment: Oh, perhaps the logic of the `if` condition is backwards? Do you want to be using the `if` block's code for the second and all later iterations, and the `else` for the first iteration only? If so, use `i != n` instead of `i == n`.

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia's article on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)),

[image: e]

This is what would feel appropriate (picking the `n` of your liking):

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
from sys import argv
from math import factorial

e = 0
n =  int(argv[1]) if len(argv) > 1 else 100 # allowing to pass a value for n as an argument
for i in range(n):
    e += 1 / factorial(i)

print(e)
```